# Can PowerShell interact with RDP prompts?

Tags: powershell, rdp

I'm currently writing a script to automate a number of checks, I have a number of clients which I want to automatically log into one of their servers or use an app hosted via RDweb.

Right now my script works fine, however, I'm only able to get to the point that it'll start to execute the RDP pointer, I'm wondering if there's a way to hit "connect":

[image]

The method I'm currently using to run this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("c:\file\path\file.rdp")
```

Is there a better way to run the .RDP file which will also allow you to "Connect"? I've also attempted to tick the "don't ask me" again, the next day it'll still prompt me with this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution I've found to start an RDP session that seems to work quite good is the following:

```
function Connect-RDP {

  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $ComputerName,

    [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
    $Credential
  )

  # take each computername and process it individually
  $ComputerName | ForEach-Object {

    # if the user has submitted a credential, store it
    # safely using cmdkey.exe for the given connection
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Credential'))
    {
      # extract username and password from credential
      $User = $Credential.UserName
      $Password = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

      # save information using cmdkey.exe
      cmdkey.exe /generic:$_ /user:$User /pass:$Password
    }

    # initiate the RDP connection
    # connection will automatically use cached credentials
    # if there are no cached credentials, you will have to log on
    # manually, so on first use, make sure you use -Credential to submit
    # logon credential

    mstsc.exe /v $_ /f
  }
}
```

Then you call it with `Connect-rdp -ComputerName myserver -Credential (Get-Credential )`.

Maybe you can adjust your script to use this cmdlet instead of your file.rdp.

I found the solution here:
https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/04/18/automatic-remote-desktop-connection/

---

Another way you could try is this:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
# Get the ID of the process
$WindowsHandle = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -Match 'Remote Desktop Connection' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id
# Activate the window
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate($WindowsHandle) | Out-Null
# SendKey to connect
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{c}")
```

`%{c}` stands for ALT+C

The modifier keys are:

```
Key  | Code
-----------
SHIFT  +
CTRL   ^
ALT    %
```